# Parts of the object disappear when it move away from the camera

Tags: rendering, clipping, z-fighting

I am making an animation of three layers of tape.

However, as I move away from the camera, the layer that should be at the top becomes partially invisible.
[image]
[image]
This happens in the view port as well.

Rendering Setting is Evee, since this is a test render, I set sampling to 8. (This also happened when I rendered at 500).

This is happening in both Blender 3.0.0/Blender 3.0.0 Alpha.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens here is a common problem called z-fighting. Basically, it's two surface that are so close together that Blender doesn't know which one he should put on top of the other. It usually is very noticeable when the distance between the surfaces and the camera is very big compared to the distance between the two surfaces, so the further your camera is, more difficult it becomes for Blender to "see" which surface is on top of each other.

To fix it you can use the **camera clipping** (as they say [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/3d_view.html#depth-buffer-glitches)) or you can modify your objects in a way that the two surfaces are not too close.

The second one may not be an option for you so here is how you can fix it with the clipping thing :

Select your camera and go to the `Properties Panel > Object Data Properties > Lens` :

[image]

There you have two settings `Clip Start` and `(Clip) End`. The `Clip start`is defaulted to something like `0.01m`, increase it slightly to a few meters (around `5m` looks like a good value for me). This will reduce the z-fighting artifacts.

Just be aware that `Clip Start` will make the objects close to the camera invisible so don't set it to high. Basically `Clip Start` value to `5m` means that every object that are less than 5 meters away from the camera are going to be invisible. You just need to set it high enough to remove the z-fighting.

You have also Clipping options for the viewport :

Press <kbd>N</kbd> on the 3D viewport and go to the view tab :

[image]

This is what you see with the default `0.01` :

[image]

But if I set it just to `1` :

[image]

Just be aware that if you get close to the object with clipping set too high, you'll have this :

[image]

Comment: Mr.mqbaka
 Sorry for the late reply...
And thank you very much for your kind answer!
I am a beginner, but I understand perfectly.

Of course I did some research on my own, but I could not reach "z-fighting"
So very very helpful for me!

The number 5.98 was also just perfect. There is no z-fighting at all.

Let me say thank you so much again.

Comment: You're welcome. We do live in different timezones after all so late replays are not deadly sins :D

Comment: I am very happy to receive such wonderful kindness from people from countries I have never visited.
Thank you also for the Edit Sugget.
I'm sure it will be a valuable post for a first-timer like me.